# Angular ngx-bootstrap datepicker how to limit future month and year

Tags: angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BoNw.png)

.html file

```
<input class="form-control" name="dp" placeholder="MM/YYYY" bsDatepicker [(ngModel)]="currentMonth"
                  #d="bsDatepicker" (ngModelChange)="onDateChange($event)" (onShown)="onOpenCalendar($event)"
                  [bsConfig]="{dateInputFormat: 'MM/YYYY'}" />
```

.ts file

```
  onOpenCalendar(container) {
    container.monthSelectHandler = (event: any): void => {
      container._store.dispatch(container._actions.select(event.date));
    };     
    container.setViewMode('month');
    endDate: new Date();
  }
```

I need to hidden future months and year. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a min & max Date attribute for the input field.

html

```
    <input class="form-control"
           placeholder="Datepicker"
           ngModel
           bsDatepicker
           [minDate]="minDate"
           [maxDate]="maxDate">
```

component

```
export class DemoDatepickerMinMaxComponent {
  minDate: Date;
  maxDate: Date;
 
  constructor() {
    this.minDate = new Date();
    this.maxDate = new Date();
    this.minDate.setDate(this.minDate.getDate() - 1);
    this.maxDate.setDate(this.maxDate.getDate() + 7);
  }
}
```

see the example on the ngx bootstrap website:
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#min-max

Comment: It's working fine Thanks. How to change green color to blue??

Comment: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#themes please read the documentation first. You can find this stuff so easily with it.